# WebdriverIO cannot find Android RN app element using TestID

Tags: appium, webdriver-io, appium-android

Using webdriverIO, I am testing android app developed using React Native.

The Dev has added `TestID` in the next button.

```js
< IconButton

//......

testID = {
  "nextIconButton"
}
/>
```

I can inspect it using Appium Inspector and I can see the `id nextIconButton`.

Learning from this [blog](https://dev.to/nextlevelbeard/an-end-to-the-abuse-of-accessibility-ids-5d2j) post , I tried doing these , but WebdriverIO cannot find the element, therefore cannot click it.

```js
//https://dev.to/nextlevelbeard/an-end-to-the-abuse-of-accessibility-ids-5d2j
const btnNext1 =  $('id=nextIconButton');  //Doesn't work
const btnNext2 =  $('id=com.package.app("nextIconButton")');  //Doesn't work
const btnNext3 =  $('id=com.package.app(nextIconButton)');  //Doesn't work

//https://webdriver.io/docs/selectors/#id-attribute
const btnNext4 =  $('#nextIconButton');  //Doesn't work
const btnNext5 =  $('//*[#nextIconButton]');  //Doesn't work
const btnNext6 =  $('id=resource-id/nextIconButton');  //Doesn't work

btnNext1.isExisting();  //false
```

I am using `"@wdio/appium-service": "8.24.1"` and `"appium": "2.4.1"`

I can click the button using `accessibility id` and `xpath` , but not the `id`.

How to get the element by `id`?

[image]